# A theorem equivalent to Pythagorean's theorem but for bi-vectors of geometric algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras

Using Clifford algebra $Cl_{0,3}(\mathbb{R})$ one can define a 1-vector as:

$$
\mathbf{v}=X\sigma_x+Y\sigma_y+Z\sigma_z
$$

and the Pythagorean can be obtained by the geometric product $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}$:

$$
\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}=(X\sigma_x+Y\sigma_y+Z\sigma_z)^2\\
=X^2+Y^2+Z^2==||\mathbf{v}||^2
$$

---

Try the same thing but with 2-vectors:

$$
\mathbf{a}=A\sigma_x\sigma_y+B\sigma_x\sigma_z+C\sigma_z\sigma_y
$$

As the 2-basis elements are orthogonal, one can define an "area-distance" as follows:

$$
\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}=(A\sigma_x\sigma_y+B\sigma_x\sigma_z+C\sigma_z\sigma_y)^2\\
=-A^2-B^2-C^2=||\mathbf{a}||^2
$$

$$
\implies ||\mathbf{a}||=i\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}
$$

What is the geometric interpretation of the area-equivalent of the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: The magnitude of $\mathbb a$ is defined as $\lVert\mathbb a\rVert=\sqrt{\mathbb a\,\mathbb a^\sim}$, or for mixed grade, $\sqrt{\langle\mathbb a\,\mathbb a^\sim\rangle_0}$, so it's always a positive real number.

Answer (score 2):

For a vector $\mathbb v=v_1\sigma_1+v_2\sigma_2+v_3\sigma_3$ (which can be interpreted as a line segment), $v_1$ is $\pm$ the length of its projection onto the $\sigma_1$-axis. The Pythagorean theorem says that the squared length of the segment is the sum of the squared lengths of its projections on all axes.

For a bivector $\mathbb a=a_{12}\sigma_1\sigma_2+a_{13}\sigma_1\sigma_3+a_{23}\sigma_2\sigma_3$ (which can be interpreted as a plane segment), $a_{12}$ is $\pm$ the area of its projection onto the $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ plane (its "shadow"). The equivalent theorem says that the squared area of the segment is the sum of the squared areas of its projections on all coordinate planes.

Comment: This is essentially de Gua's theorem.